# how do i create multiple txt files name from a column in a CSV file

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, batch-rename

here is the code i am trying. it results in just the last line being created. so i guess the other files are being overwritten, although i tried to move them and that hasnt workeD?

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-8 delims=," %%a in ("chassisinfo.csv") do (
set hostname=%%a
set FQDN=%%b
set MGMT=%%c
set SUB=%%d
set gw=%%e
set dns=%%f
set vlan=%%g


echo # Seans scripted installation file > ks_%hostname%.cfg
echo # >> ks_%hostname%.cfg
echo # Accept the VMware End User License Agreement >> ks_%hostname%.cfg
echo vmaccepteula >> ks_%hostname%.cfg
echo # Set the root password for the DCUI and Tech Support Mode >> ks_%hostname%.cfg
echo rootpw >> ks_%hostname%.cfg
echo # The install media is in the CD-ROM drive >> ks_%hostname%.cfg
echo install --firstdisk --overwritevmfs >> ks_%hostname%.cfg
echo keyboard 'United Kingdom' >> ks_%hostname%.cfg

echo network --bootproto=static --device=vmnic0 --ip=%MGMT% --netmask=%SUB% --gateway=%gw% --nameserver=%dns% --vlanid=%vlan% --hostname=%hostname%%FQDN% >> ks_%hostname%.cfg
move ks_%hostname%.cfg d:\KSscripts\



)
```

Comment: Please explain what you expect it to do, and what it does instead. We're not telepathic

Comment: it is a script to create a CFG file for each line of the CSV. the cfg file is named by column A (hostname). each column has a different property that i use in different parts of the script. this does what i want it to do and creates the script but only for the last line in the CSV file. im not sure why it skips through the rest of the lines. although i would like it to skip the very first line of the CSV as that is where the titles/heading are and not the data. hope that is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You are recreating the file for every line because of the single > in the line.

```
echo # Seans scripted installation file > ks_%hostname%.cfg
```

change that to the line below.  Note that I also put quotes around the file name in case there are spaces in the filename.  It would be a good idea to do that in all cases.

```
echo # Seans scripted installation file >> "ks_%hostname%.cfg"
```

Then you should put a line like this on the line before you start first line of your code above to be sure that you don't append to an old file.

```
if exist "ks_%hostname%.cfg" del /f /q "ks_%hostname%.cfg"
```

Edit... To skip the first line, change your FOR statement to:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-8 skip=1 delims=," %%a in ("chassisinfo.csv") do (
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does *not* create just the last file, but the file with the last value assigned to %hostname% variable, that is, the first time the program run it should create a file just named "ks_.cfg". If the Batch code does not have a SETLOCAL command, then the second and next times it runs it creates the file with the name of the last line.

The reason for this is that %hostname% variable value is expanded *just once* before the FOR command is executed, so all cycles are executed with the same value. You may solve this problem in two ways: using the original FOR replaceable parameter instead of the variable:

```
for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1-8 delims=," %%a in ("chassisinfo.csv") do (

echo # Seans scripted installation file > ks_%%a.cfg
echo # >> ks_%%a.cfg

. . . .

move ks_%%a.cfg d:\KSscripts\

)
```

Or using *delayed expansion*: Insert `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` command at begining of your program and change all `%hostname%` expansions by `!hostname!`. For further details, look for "delayed expansion" in this site or read the explanation at `set /?`.